# Missing data after scraping

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, splinter

I am trying to scrape Google data on the top 250 IMDB movie ratings.

```
movie_list = top_250_imdb["Title"]

base_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='

streaming = []
title = []
price = []

for movie in movie_list:
    query_url = (f'{base_url}{movie}')

    browser.visit(query_url)

    time.sleep(5)

    soup = bs(browser.html, 'lxml')


    results1 = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'ellip bclEt')

    for result in results1:
        streaming.append(result.text)
        title.append(movie.capitalize())

    results2 = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'ellip rsj3fb')

    for result in results2:
        price.append(result.text)
```

After scraping, I got both the `len(streaming)` and `len(title)` = 1297
but the `len(price)` = 1296

I couldn't create a DataFrame because they are not in the same length.

What went wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: What are the `streaming` and `price` on the Google Search results page?

Answer (score 0):

I think the one of the values in price is NaN... Idk how to solve but you might get help with that...

Try to create a dataframe with price only... Then fill the NaN value using fillna function and then join that price dataframe with your main dataframe....

A bit long but might work

Answer (score 0):

just a small change is needed here to monitor the missing values ...

```
    results2 = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'ellip rsj3fb')

    for result in results2:
        if result is not None :
            p = None #u can even replace with 0 but for our convinience it is None here    
        else :
            p = result.text
        price.append(p)
```

now u can check the len of the list named "price" and that missing count would also be added

u can add this piece of code while append values to the "streaming" and "title" lists so that if it encounters any missing values it replaces with the provided value instead of abandoning that action.

just replace the above code with the below and just have a look at indentation and it works fine.

```
movie_list = top_250_imdb["Title"]

base_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='

streaming = []
title = []
price = []

for movie in movie_list:
    query_url = (f'{base_url}{movie}')

    browser.visit(query_url)

    time.sleep(5)

    soup = bs(browser.html, 'lxml')


    results1 = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'ellip bclEt')

    for result in results1:
        streaming.append(result.text)
        title.append(movie.capitalize())

    results2 = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'ellip rsj3fb')

    for result in results2:
        if result is not None :
            p = None #u can even replace with 0 but for our convinience it is None here    
        else :
            p = result.text
        price.append(p)
```

Hope this helps ..

Comment: thank you, i tried but it didn't work. For example, the movie "Once Upon a Time in the West", it's available on CBS, but the it doesn't have a price, so I couldn't scrape the price for CBS. I tried to use "Try Except", but it also didn't give any errors, so it didn't work.